# PHP APC doesn't seem to work : uptime is allways 0

Tags: php, nginx, apc, uptime

After installing APC on a VPS with CentOS/Nginx/8G Ram, apc.php always shows uptime = 0 minutes, this is my apc configuration :

```
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=512M
apc.num_files_hint=10000
apc.user_entries_hint=10000
apc.max_file_size=5M
apc.stat=0
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.cache_by_default=1
apc.include_once_override=1
```

I restared nginx afeter updating php.ini, the website seems to be faster than before, do you thing "uptime=0" is normal value ?

Comment: PS : nothing found in stackoverflow :(

Comment: You installed APC on nginx with mod fastcgi?

Comment: I'm not sure :( how can I check this ? I have this in phpinfo : Server API = CGI/FastCGI

Comment: Yes its fastcgi. You should post this in server fault. Theres a lot to be checked